# JQuery | Fetch HTML from URL and display it in div every 3 seconds without duplicates?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a live logging system that logs certain events that happen on the site. Such as a user logging in, a user registering, or a user that ran into the 404 page.

A PHP file fetches the data from the database then displays it as `<li>A user logged in</li>`
The PHP file is apart of my API which requires a key.

This is the code I use in my front end to fetch the HTML that is displayed from my API.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logs").load('https://example.com/api/get_html_logs');
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#logs").load('https://example.com/api/get_html_logs').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 3000);
});
```

It successfully displays the HTML list from my API, and it refreshes every 3 seconds to fetch new data. No duplicates are found in the `<div>`.

Now if I try to use my key to access the PHP file, I cannot pass headers using jQuery .load(), and instead I use this:

```js
$.ajax({
   url: "https://example.com/api/get_html_logs",
   headers : {Auth : '<?php echo $this->settings->personal_key ?>'}       
 }).done(function(data) {
        
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#logs").append(data);
        }, 3000);
        
});
```

This runs successfully every 3 seconds, but displays duplicate HTML data in the `<div>` element.

Here is my PHP file:

```php
<?php
namespace Blaze\Controllers;

use Blaze\Middlewares\Authentication;
use Blaze\Database\Database;

class APIMarkupLogs extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        Authentication::gaurd_api();

            $result = Database::$database->query('SELECT * FROM `logs` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC');
            
            $payload = array();
                    
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                
              echo '<li><span class="badge badge-'. $row['badge_type'] .'">'. $row['type'] .'</span>'. $row['timestamp'] .' ~ '. $row['log_text'] .'</li>';
               
            }
    }
}
?>
```

How do I make my ajax request similar to the .load() request in my case? Without getting duplicates in the `<div>` that I want my HTML displayed in? I want it to fetch new data every 3 seconds. Is their a way to do it better?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM logs` ... `WHERE timestamp > <last_timestamp> ` ... ` ORDER BY timestamp DESC` ?

Comment: This is because I also want to fetch past logs and load them into the <div>. As well as getting the new logs that occur. Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: yeah, just give no timestamp in the first request and then ask your db for the newer records, giving `WHERE timestamp > last_timestamp_got` or better `WHERE id > last_record_id`

Comment: Ok, but when the HTML generated from that SQL query is displayed, jquery will continue to fetch the same HTML every 3 seconds, creating duplicates in the `div` that I want it displayed in.

Comment: so change it to return json with html and last id, and then send requests with last id, so the php script would return only thsese results (with greater id)

Comment: Could you provide a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$.ajax()` set up is only making one request that returns an html string. Your `setInterval()` keeps appending that same string over and over...all from the initial request.

Wrap the $.ajax in a function that you call each time. Then in success use `html()` to replace existing content rather than `append()` which keeps adding to existing;

```
function loadData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/api/get_html_logs",
    headers: {
      Auth: '<?php echo $this->settings->personal_key ?>'
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    // replace all elements in #logs with html()
    $("#logs").html(data);    
  }).finally(function() {
     // do it again in 3 seconds
    setTimeout(loadData, 3000)
  });

}
// start the loading
loadData()
```